# How is ${E}(Z)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, proof-explanation

Let $(X, Y)$ be an $\mathbb{R}^{2}$-valued random variable with density given by

$$
f(x, y)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$

for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Define

$$
Z:= \begin{cases}Y / X & X>0 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$

Question: Find

$$
\mathrm{E}(Y \mid X), \quad \mathrm{E}\left(Y^{2} \mid X\right), \quad \mathrm{E}(Z \mid X),  \quad \mathrm{E}(Y)
$$

Solution:
We have $Y=Z X$ and find

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}(Y \mid X) & =\mathrm{E}(Z X \mid X)=X \mathrm{E}(Z \mid X)=X \mathrm{E}(Z)=\frac{X}{2} \\
\mathrm{E}\left(Y^{2} \mid X\right) & =\mathrm{E}\left(Z^{2} X^{2} \mid X\right)=X^{2} \mathrm{E}\left(Z^{2}\right)=\frac{X^{2}}{3} \\
\mathrm{E}(Z \mid X) & =\mathrm{E}(Z)=\frac{1}{2} \\
\mathrm{E}(Y) & =\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(Y \mid X))=\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{X}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

---

---

In the above solution, I'm trying to understand the following:

how is ${E}(Z)=\frac{1}{2}$?
how is ${E}\left(Z^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$?
And how is ${E}\left(\frac{X}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$?

Help would be appreciated. This is not a homework question so feel completely free to answer. I'm just trying to understand the material. Thank you.

Comment: As $Z$ is a quotient of two joint variables, you should be able to just use the law of the unconscious statistician, i.e., compute the integral $\iint \frac{y}{x^2} \ dx \ dy$ over an appropriate region. Now repeat for $Z^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[X] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} x f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^1 x \cdot \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \, dy \, dx = \int_0^1 x \, dx = \frac{1}{2}.$$

$$E[Z] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{y}{x} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x y \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \, dx = \frac{1}{2}.$$

$$E[Z^2] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{y^2}{x^2} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^3} \int_0^x y^2 \, dy \,dx = \frac{1}{3}  \int_0^1 \, dx = \frac{1}{3}.$$